# Mongodb Sub String and aggregation problen

Tags: spring-boot

how to write this query in spring With mongodb application

```
db.Light.aggregate({$group: {_id : {$substr : ["$dateAndTime", 4,4]}, count:{"$avg" :"$lightIntensity"}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here am able to get query in Springboot it's working very well......

String jsonData;
          TypedAggregation agg =  newAggregation(LightModel.class, project("lightIntensity").andExpression("substr(dateAndTime,4,4)").as("time"),group("time")
          .avg("lightIntensity").as("lightIntensity") );

```
      AggregationResults<DBObject> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,DBObject.class); 
      List<DBObject> resultList = result.getMappedResults();

      System.out.println("resultList"+resultList);
      jsonData = new Gson().toJson(resultList);
      System.out.println("jsonData"+jsonData);
```